# Google cloud automatic deploy fails due to bad cloudbuild.yaml

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to automatically deploy a flask-based python3.6 app using the flexible environment of google app engine.

This is my cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  args: ['clone', 'https://github.com/{PATH_TO_MY_REPO}']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/{MY_PROJECT_ID}/appengine', '.']
```

The first step succeeds but the second one throws the following messages:

> Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
>
> unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile
>   path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

I'm trying to build all my codebase but have no idea how to do it explicitly.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you check if the Dockerfile actually is where it should be?

Comment: @arudzinska what do you mean by that? explain yourself please

Comment: @arudzinska yes, i checked multiple times. I gave up however, thanks for trying to help.